# bash string manipulation using sed/regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Through bash, I am trying to extract part of a line from a file.

Currently I am using two sed commands back to back like so:

`sed -n -e "s/^abc=//p" file | sed -n -e "s/\.//gp"`

which can take in `abc=1.2.3` and spit out `123`.  This got me thinking... Can I achieve this with just one command call?  As in I want to find all strings in a file that match `abc=<digit1>\.<digit2>\.<digit3>` and spit out `<digit1><digit2><digit3>`.

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I want this to only print out lines that match.  For instance, if I have the following file:

```
1.2.3.4
abc=quack
qtip=1.2.3
abc=1.2.3
abc = 4.5.6
```

running the command should only print `123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below GNU sed command is the string `abc=<digit1>\.<digit2>\.<digit3>` present anywhere in a file,

```
sed -nr 's/.*abc=([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9]).*/\1\2\3/p' file
```

OR

You could try the below sed command if the string `abc=` is at the start of a line.

```
sed -nr 's/^abc=([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9]).*/\1\2\3/p' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
abc=1.2.3
foo abc=4.5.6
bar
$ sed -nr 's/.*abc=([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9]).*/\1\2\3/p' file
123
456
$ sed -nr 's/^abc=([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9]).*/\1\2\3/p' file
123
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` instead for removing `.` from part after `abc=`:

```
awk -F= '$1=="abc"{gsub(/\./, "", $2); print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `awk` that will work with any number of digits, not just three, separated by periods:

```
$ echo 'abc=1.2.3.4' | awk -F. -v OFS= '{sub(/.*=/, "", $1); print}'
1234
$ echo 'abc=1.2' | awk -F. -v OFS= '{sub(/.*=/, "", $1); print}'
12
```

Taking the `awk` command in parts:

- `-F.`

  Use a period as the field separator.  If the input is `abc=1.2`, for example, then `awk` sees two fields: `abc=1` and `2`.
- `-v OFS=`

  This tells `awk` not to put any spaces between the fields when we print them out.
- `sub(/.*=/, "", $1)`

  This removes the `abc=` part from the beginning of the line.
- `print`

  This prints out the final line.

#### Selecting which lines to process

Suppose that we only want to process lines starting with `abc=` and followed *only* by numbers and periods.  In that case:

```
$ awk -F. -v OFS= '/^abc=[0-9.]+$/ {sub(/.*=/, "", $1); print}' sample
123
```

where `sample` is the name of the file containing the sample lines in the updated question.

The sole change above is the addition of the pattern `/^abc=[0-9.]+$/`.  This limits the commands which follow to only apply  to lines matching this regular expression.  Since `/^abc=[0-9.]+$/` only matches lines that start with `abc=` followed by any combination of numbers of periods, only those lines are processed.  Non-matching lines are ignored.

Comment: This works to remove the abc= and also the dots, but it does it for every line in the file.  I need it to print out only the lines that start with 'abc='

Comment: @user972276 That can be done.  The answer is now updated according the current edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -E 's/abc=|([0-9])\./\1/g' file
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying "/bin/sed: invalid option -- E".  If I use "-e" I get a complaint about '\3' in conjunction with the 's' command.  The man page does not include a '-E' option

Comment: Which version of bash are you using? I've updated my answer, so maybe that will fare you better.

Comment: I am using version 4.1.5 on a RHEL 5.9 box

Comment: @user972276, `-E` should work with that. Try replacing it with `-r` perhaps. `echo 'abc=1.2.3.4.5' | sed -r 's/abc=|([0-9])\./\1/g'
`

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use tr:

```
$ tr -d [a-z.=] <<< abc=1.2.3
123
```

EDIT: I missed the part of the question where '*I want to find all strings in a file that match...*' So this might or might not work depending on the content of the other, unwanted, lines.

Comment: Nice one — a person that thinks outside the box!

Comment: For my specific use at the moment, it will only find one in the file, but for future reference its nice to know more generally how to do things :)